# PageViewController scroll bug (over scrolls)

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I was following the tutorial [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/) and had to make a few changes to fit my project ([code of my variation here](https://github.com/mlelien/CoachmarksTest), sorry I put it on GitHub because it's a bit lengthy to copy and paste). Sometimes when I swipe right to get to the last VC, it automatically closes on sight. Other times it works properly where if I swipe to the last VC it stays there until I swipe right again to close it. I've placed print statements in the code to help me find where the bug is. Here are the [print statements when it works](https://github.com/mlelien/CoachmarksTest/blob/master/Works) and [when it doesn't work](https://github.com/mlelien/CoachmarksTest/blob/master/Doesn't%20Work). Looking at the logs, since the exact same code is accessed in the same order, I'm not sure how to fix this bug. This problem doesn't occur when the transition style is `PageCurl` instead of `Scroll`.

Comment: Please don't make me link to some other page just to see your logs. Or your relevant code.

Comment: Can you explain what "closes on sight" means? I can't even tell what the problem is. You haven't made any attempt to describe the architecture of the situation.

Comment: @stumped Did you get a solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know how pageViewControllers work.
After the first page is loaded, the moment you start to scroll it will try to load the next page. this is just for the first page. after that as soon as you reach a page it will preload the next page (depending on the direction) and have it ready.

In your case when you reach page 5 the pageViewController will try to **preload** the next page which leads to this part of your code

```
guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {

        print("last item in coachamrks going to dismiss")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        return orderedViewControllers.first
    }
```

and it will dismiss the viewController as soon as you reach page 5.
This is not a bug. It's the default behavior of pageViewController.

I think the reason that you sometimes find it behaving the way you wrongly expected is that when you scroll through the pages fast enough the pageViewController stops preloading pages for performance reasons.

The only way you could achieve what you want is a hackish way of accessing the scrollView inside of the pageViewController but it is not safe and might break your app if Apple changes the architecture of pageViewControllers in a future update.

I suggest you put a button in the last page and use it to dismiss the pageViewController.